# Yii condition and params not working

Tags: php, yii

I'm having problem binding params on CDbCriteria,
the code below didn't work

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "(arrival_date > ':start_date' and arrival_date < ':end_date')";
$criteria->params = array(":start_date" => $getStart, ":end_date" => $getEnd);

$admissionList = Admission::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

but this one works fine

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "(arrival_date > '$getStart' and arrival_date < '$getEnd')";

$admissionList = Admission::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

why?

Comment: What means its not working? Have you tried removing the `'` from the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "(arrival_date > :start_date and arrival_date < :end_date)";
$criteria->params = array(":start_date" => $getStart, ":end_date" => $getEnd);

$admissionList = Admission::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $admissionList=Admission::model()->findAll("arrival_data>:getStart AND arrival_data<:getEnd",array(":getStart"=>$getStart,":getEnd"=>$getEnd));
```